# how to create multiple threads pools for one method in spring boot using @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool

I have a method but want to create multiple thread pools. currently i am writing under way

```
@Async ("poolProcessor1")
method A1 () {
// Handle similar logic A2
}


@Async ("poolProcessor2")
method A2 () {
// Handle similar logic A1

}
```

Is there a way I can create multiple thread pools on the same method? Can you please help me with suggestions or keywords.
I use Java spring boot

Comment: What benefit do you hope to gain by having two on one method?

Comment: Because when modifying, I just need to edit in the same place, these 2 methods are identical, leading to duplication of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread pool without method level Async annotation (illustrated below). You can programmatically decide which thread pool to use for different logics.

```
@Autowired
private Executor poolProcessor1;

@Autowired
private Executor poolProcessor2;

method A1 () {
  poolProcessor1.execute(()->...execute come logic or method)
  poolProcessor2.execute(()->...execute come logic or method)
}
```